# Java Spring REST + MongoDB (custom URI? using MongoDB Template instead of respository class? what about the xml config files?)

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, rest

I currently have been reading and trying out `MongoDB` with `Spring` REST framework.

I have the following code for the controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/info2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<User> getAllUser(){
        List<User> users = userRepo.findByEmail("test@test.com");
        return users;
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public User createUser(@RequestBody User user){
        return userRepo.save(user);
    }
}
```

However, when I call
**localhost:8080/users**, it returns back

```
{
_links: {
self: {
href: "http://localhost:8080/users{?page,size,sort}"
templated: true
}-
search: {
href: "http://localhost:8080/users/search"
}-
}-
page: {
size: 20
totalElements: 0
totalPages: 0
number: 0
}-
}
```

I want the URI **/users/info2** to return back the list of users by that particular email. How do I do that?

Also, here are the outstanding questions I have:

1. Can I just use `MongoDBTemplate` instead of the `MongoRepository`? I want more customized queries, and I couldn't find any in depth examples on the web.
2. How does `Spring` framework map the xml config file, for example, in cases like when I setup multiple MongoDB connections?

Comment: Can you post your repository please and your config file. This looks like you have RepositoryRestController turned on because it is the default HATEOAS response on that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

So without your configs, but looking at your existing code and service response, one can make some general assumptions. Your Repository is annotated with @RepositoryRestController which not only provides Spring Data access but also exposes a common ReST endpoint for your repository.

This can be determined from two aspects of your post. First you don't appear to be using HATEOAS in your Controller class, yet your service exposes JSON + HAL. Furthermore your response exposes the paging and sorting feature of Mongo Repository as well as the search behavior of Spring Data Repositories when annotated with @RepositoryRestController.

If you don't want this behavior, change the annotation on your Repository to @Repository instead.

Also to answer your other questions: 
1. you can annotate methods if you want with queries on Spring Data Repositories, you can also use any class in the stack managed by spring you want, but why?

2. I suggest reading about the bean lifecycle to understand the dependency management within spring, there are plenty of presentations (including one in my github repo). If you have multiple connections, you can define your repository beans to utilize anything you wire it. There is a lot more manual operations at that point, and it will take some understanding and through to make it work. There is no way to give you a simple "do xyz" type answer without a lot more information.

Comment: If you could point me to a tutorial or even code that expose some of the aspects of those feature describe above. I will be able to figure out how it works. I guess the best way to learn is reading the code itself.

Comment: If you want code, look at the spring framework on github. You can get the lifecycle. If you want to get the concepts of SpringBoot, again spring.io is the best source.